# Start Selenium in Raspberry Pi from crontab exit abnormally

Tags: python, selenium, cron, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to launch a simple Python script using selenium library from the crontab but it doesn't work.

I'm on a RaspberryPi 3B+. A screen is connected by HDMI port.
The Python script is located in the directory /home/pi/Documents/

The code works fine when launched from terminal.

Here is the code I tried to launch (test2.py):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.BinaryLocation = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser"
driver_path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(driver_path), options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Here is my crontab file :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/test2.py > /home/pi/Documents/logs.txt 2>&1
```

Here is my logs.txt file :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/pi/Documents/test2.py", line 11, in <module>
>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(driver_path), options=chrome_options)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
> line 80, in __init__
>     super().__init__(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py",
> line 104, in __init__
>     super().__init__(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 286, in __init__
>     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 378, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 440, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
> line 245, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.   (unknown error:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
> chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so
> ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I tried for days to debug this but with no success:

1. I replaced in my code the driver path by /usr/bin/chromiumdriver
2. I replaced in my code the BinaryLocation by
   /usr/bin/chromium-browser
3. I add in crontab file DISPLAY=:0
4. I add in crontab file
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/loal/bin:usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/chromium-b$
5. I add in crontab file the
   PATH=<return_of_command_echo_$PATH_launched_from_terminal_in_/home/pi/Documents>
6. I re-installed selenium
7. I Installed webdriver-manager

I saw these kind of issues many times in the web but I didn't find a solution which solved mine. Could you provide some help please ?